# MySQL UTF8 Issue

Tags: mysql, unicode

Okay, I have tried to import "CSV" file into MySQL for the past 24 hours but have failed miserably. 
I have set name, set char and there is nothing left that I have not set to UTF8 but it still is not working. Not just for the DB and Tables, but for the server as well, still no use. 
I am importing directly into MySQL so it is not PHP issue. I will be grateful if anyone can highlight where am I going wrong.

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE DATABASE `dict_2`;
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------+
| Database | Create Database
                     |
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------+
| dict_2   | CREATE DATABASE `dict_2` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLAT
E utf8_unicode_ci */ |
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show variables like "%character%"; show variables like "%collation%";
+--------------------------+--------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                          |
+--------------------------+--------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                           |
| character_set_connection | utf8                           |
| character_set_database   | utf8                           |
| character_set_filesystem | utf8                           |
| character_set_results    | utf8                           |
| character_set_server     | utf8                           |
| character_set_system     | utf8                           |
| character_sets_dir       | C:\xampp\mysql\share\charsets\ |
+--------------------------+--------------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
+----------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name        | Value           |
+----------------------+-----------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8_unicode_ci |
+----------------------+-----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: "where am I going wrong" --- you are asking a question completely wrong. At the moment it's impossible to answer it.

Comment: In its current form the question is impossible to answer. The question gives no indication of what the failure mode is, the behavior that's observed; there's no mention that you're using the LOAD DATA statement, just a vague "importing directly to MySQL"...  are typing in "import my.csv" at the command prompt? we're just guessing.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. **It was the file encoding.**

I thought I had considered everything and had set my Sublime encoding to UTF8 but when tested it on Windows VM it turned out that it was not utf8. I have still got some other issue with the encoding but would like to try have a go at it personally before screaming help again.

Thank you very much once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In its current form, this question is impossible to answer.

We're left guessing...

That you're using a MySQL `LOAD DATA` statement.

You've verified that the characterset encoding of the .csv file is **not** `ucs2`.

You've verified that the characterset encoding of the .csv file is `utf8` (i.e. matches the `character_set_database` system variable), of that you've specified the appropriate characterset in the `CHARACTER SET` clause of the LOAD DATA statement.

Beyond that, there's a whole slew of other things that might be wrong, but we're still just guessing.

Very frequently when something MySQL "fail miserably", there's some sort of indication, like an error message, or some other behavior that we can observe and describe.

In the question, the description of the failure mode is beyond vague, it's entirely non-existent.